# MS Access Query Criteria IIf true then <

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have an MS Access 2007 query with the criteria as follows - but it doesn't work!

```
IIf([Forms]![CSL_CSD_Log]![Reason_Category]=1,<6,[Forms]![CSL_CSD_Log]![Reason_Category])
```

I can't work out why the TRUE result doesn't give me all values that are <6.
If I simply put <6 as the criteria - it works fine.
Essentially I want to display ALL records, apart from those with an ID of 6.

Am I missing something??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the SQL of your query? I think you would need to `EVAL` your IIf Statement for it to work in the way you expect.

Comment: @Minty here's my SQL code  'SELECT TBL_Descriptor_Values.Descriptor_ID, TBL_Descriptor_Values.Descriptor, TBL_Descriptor_Values.Descriptor_Category
FROM TBL_Descriptor_Values
WHERE (((TBL_Descriptor_Values.Descriptor_Category)=IIf([Forms]![CSL_CSD_Log]![Reason_Category]=1,(TBL_Descriptor_Values.Descriptor_Category)<6,[Forms]![CSL_CSD_Log]![Reason_Category])) AND ((TBL_Descriptor_Values.Enabled)=Yes))
ORDER BY TBL_Descriptor_Values.Order;'

Answer (score 0):

Go to **SQL** view and try for the *where* clause:

```
WHERE 
    IIF([Forms]![CSL_CSD_Log]![Reason_Category] = 1, [FieldToFilter] < 6, [FieldToFilter] = [Forms]![CSL_CSD_Log]![Reason_Category])
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses, they took me in another direction & I managed to get it to work as needed.
It might not be the prettiest bit of coding, but hey :)

```
SELECT TBL_Descriptor_Values.Descriptor_ID, TBL_Descriptor_Values.Descriptor, 
TBL_Descriptor_Values.Descriptor_Category
FROM TBL_Descriptor_Values
WHERE (((IIf([Forms]![CSL_CSD_Log]![Reason_Category]<2,[TBL_Descriptor_Values].            
[Descriptor_Category]))<6) AND ((TBL_Descriptor_Values.Enabled)=-1)) OR 
(((TBL_Descriptor_Values.Enabled)=-1) AND ((IIf([Forms]![CSL_CSD_Log]! 
[Reason_Category]=4,[TBL_Descriptor_Values].[Descriptor_Category]))=4)) OR 
(((TBL_Descriptor_Values.Enabled)=-1) AND ((IIf([Forms]![CSL_CSD_Log]! 
[Reason_Category]=5,[TBL_Descriptor_Values].[Descriptor_Category]))=5)) OR 
(((TBL_Descriptor_Values.Enabled)=-1) AND ((IIf([Forms]![CSL_CSD_Log]! 
[Reason_Category]=6,[TBL_Descriptor_Values].[Descriptor_Category]))=6))
ORDER BY TBL_Descriptor_Values.Order;
```

Thanks again.